# Crontab is running but still not executing command Django

Tags: python, django, cron

I am trying to execute a command through [Django Crontab](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab) everyday. Here is what I am doing:

First, I added `django_crontab` in `INSTALLED_APPS`

FYI, I have written a Django command `sendalerts` which is working perfectly fine

Now I am trying to run that command through `crontab` on regular intervals

This is what I added in my `settings.py`

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('* * * * *', 'django.core.management.call_command', ['sendalerts']),
]
```

When I run this command through `python manage.py crontab add` it doesn't give any error. It also list down cronJob when I check with this command `python manage.py crontab show`

But problem is it doesn't execute the code which is written in my `sendalerts` command.

What can I do to check what is that I am doing wrong or what can be the error which I can fix to make it work?

**Edit:**
Output of `crontab -e` is

```
 * * * * * /usr/local/bin/python /home/wukla/app/app/manage.py crontab run 455e70156896954803547b6f6d845f9b # django-cronjobs for app
```

Comment: Is the command added to your crontab (```sudo crontab -e``` then ```:q ``` + [enter] to quit)? Do you see any output logs in your crontab logs? (find your crontab log files using this ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log)

Comment: @Orysza yes command is added but I am unable to see any logs files. Tried to check logs according to all given solutions but still unable to find logs file

Comment: @Orysza I have edited my question and added output of `crontab -e`, you can check if you want

Comment: It's a bit strange there is a star missing in your crontab. Is it a typo? Have you tried setting up a very simple cron job manually? I am not familiar with Django and cannot help you with the Django aspects of the question.

Comment: @Orysza sorry that was a typo. I guess I should try a simple cron job first as you have suggested

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple issue with this. The one's I have encountered are:

1) If your script is using any PATH variable from system then that has to be added to crontab manually.

2) You should add a relative path to your script to run.

3) Crontab entry should always have a newline at the end of the file.

These are all I thing I have come across as errors while using crontab.

Hope this might help you.

Comment: As you can see I don't think that there is any PATH involved and also Crontab entry is added in settings.py not in crontab file. As much as I know I don't think that there is any of problem mentioned above